# Spring Kafka : Skip error message using CommonErrorHandler

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka 2.8.9 and kafka-clients 2.8.1 . I want to skip a message which is failed to de-serialize . Since  setErrorHandler is deprecated , I tried using  CommonErrorHandler . But I am not sure how to skip current error message and move to next record . The only option I can see is using pattern matching by extracting relevant details from below line like offset and partition .

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition test-0 at offset 1. If needed, please seek past the record
```

Is there any other way like RecordDeserializationException to get necessary information from the exception or any other means without pattern matching . I can not upgrade to kafka 3.X.X  .

My config

```
 @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Farewell> farewellConsumerFactory()
    {
        groupId = LocalTime.now().toString();

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put( ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,  bootstrapAddress);
        props.put( ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props,new StringDeserializer(),new JsonDeserializer<>(Farewell.class));
    }



    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Farewell>  farewellKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Farewell> factory =   new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new CommonErrorHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleOtherException(Exception thrownException, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container, boolean batchListener)
            {

                CommonErrorHandler.super.handleOtherException(thrownException, consumer, container, batchListener);
            }
        });
        factory.setConsumerFactory(farewellConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

My listener class

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${topicId}",
            containerFactory = "farewellKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void farewellListener(Farewell message) {
        System.out.println("Received Message in group " + groupId + "| " + message);
    }
```

Domain class

```
public class Farewell {

    private String message;
    private Integer remainingMinutes;

    public Farewell(String message, Integer remainingMinutes)
    {
        this.message = message;
        this.remainingMinutes = remainingMinutes;
    }

    // standard getters, setters and constructor
}
```

I have checked these links
[How to skip a msg that have error in kafka when i use ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66916925/how-to-skip-a-msg-that-have-error-in-kafka-when-i-use-concurrentmessagelistenerc)

[Better way of error handling in Kafka Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63236346/better-way-of-error-handling-in-kafka-consumer)

Comment: @Gary Russell please help here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [ErrorHandlingDeserializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer) as a wrapper around your real deserializer.

Serialization exceptions will be sent directly to the `DefaultErrorHandler`, which treats such exceptions as fatal (by default) and sends them directly to the recoverer.